# Trying to get user IP, referrer data in PHP- Why doesn't this code work?

Tags: php

The following code:

```
<?php
    // Get referrer:
    $ref=@$HTTP_REFERER; 
    echo "<b>Referrer of this page  = $ref </b><br>";

    // Get IP:
    $ip=@$REMOTE_ADDR; 
    echo "<b>IP Address= $ip</b><br>";
?>
```

Returns:

**Referrer of this page = 

IP Address=**

Why wouldn't this work? Thanks-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

And

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Answer (score 11):

`$HTTP_REFERER` and `$REMOTE_ADDR` are not defined because [`register_globals`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) is turned off.

Use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` instead. Do *not* turn on `register_globals`.

Comment: @Oswald- Thanks, helpful answer, though James just beat you

Comment: @Yarin This is not a speed contest. If anything, this is a quality contest.

Comment: +1 just for suggesting *not* to turn on `register_globals`. They're EVILL!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what James posted, you can also try:

`getenv('HTTP_REFERER');` and `getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');`

if his don't work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're reading some outdated info or code somewhere, probably PHP 4 era. What version of PHP are you currently working with?

For info on what is predefined in current PHP versions and standard configurations, please see 
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php.